# How to get all unique assignments between two lists

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

I have two lists that can each contain duplicate values but any value can only appear in one (or none) of the two lists.

```
A = [0,1]
B = [2,3]
```

and i want to get all unique mappings between these two lists.

```
assignment(A,B) = [((0,2),(1,3)), ((0,3),(1,2))]
```

I know that this can be done for example using itertools.permutations.
There can however be duplicates in either/both of the lists and then this approach would give me duplicates because i do not care about the order of the assignments. Because for every possible assignment i want to just find the total distance.

```
A = [1,1]
B = [2,3]
mapping(A,B) = [((1,2),(1,3)), ((1,3),(1,2))]
```

with the desired output being

```
mapping(A,B) = [((1,2),(1,3))]
```

If just the first list had duplicated i could achieve this using sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations. Although that also wouldnt work for me because it doesnt play nice with numba

However the second list can also have duplicated and then even with that i would get results like

```
A = [0,1]
B = [3,3]
mapping(A,B) = [((0,3),(1,3)), ((1,3),(0,3))]
```

with the desired output being

```
mapping(A,B) = [((0,3),(1,3))]
```

Also ideally i would like to have the code in a way that it works with numba.
Is my best way to just produce all permutations of A, put them through a set to filter out duplicates and then just do the extra work of just evaluating the duplicate options on B? (It wont give wrong results just slow the code down)

Currently my best guess is that i have to do

```
AB = [list(zip(perm, B)) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B)))]
```

with

```
@njit
def permutations(A, k):
    """Calculates permutation of k elements in A. Needed because numba doesnt like itertools"""
    r = [[i for i in range(0)]]
    for i in range(k):
        r = [[a] + b for a in A for b in r if (a in b) == False]
    return r
```

and just do the extra work for cases where B has duplicates.

Edit:
I now got a two versions that give the desired result:

`set(tuple(sorted(zip(perm, B))) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B))))`

and

`set(tuple(sorted(zip(A, p))) for p in permutations(B))`

and the previous version that produces duplicates that come from the second array

`[zip(perm, B) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B)))]`

I also tested which version is the fastest for my concrete usecase:

```
from itertools import product, permutations
import timeit
import numpy as np
A = [0,0,1,1]
B = [2,3,3,3]
mem = np.arange(5)

def vers1(A,B,mem):
    res = float("inf")
    for mapping in set(tuple(sorted(zip(A, p))) for p in permutations(B)):
        temp = 0
        for a, b in mapping:
            temp += abs(mem[a]-mem[b])
        res = min(res,temp)
    return res
    
def vers2(A,B,mem):
    res = float("inf")
    for mapping in set(tuple(sorted(zip(perm, B))) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B)))):
        temp = 0
        for a, b in mapping:
            temp += abs(mem[a]-mem[b])
        res = min(res,temp)
    return res
    
def vers3(A,B,mem):
    res = float("inf")
    for mapping in [zip(perm, B) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B)))]:
        temp = 0
        for a, b in mapping:
           temp += abs(mem[a]-mem[b])
        res = min(res,temp)
    return res

print(vers1(A,B,mem))
print(timeit.timeit("vers1(A,B,mem)",'from __main__ import vers1, A, B,mem'))
print(vers2(A,B,mem))
print(timeit.timeit("vers2(A,B,mem)",'from __main__ import vers2, A, B,mem'))
print(vers3(A,B,mem))
print(timeit.timeit("vers3(A,B,mem)",'from __main__ import vers3, A, B,mem'))
```

and got this result:

```
9
58.46571195700017
9
23.15174284099703
9
28.064288804998796
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a set to remove the duplicates

```
import itertools as it

A=[0,1]
B=[3,3]
AB = list(set(tuple(zip(A, p)) for p in it.permutations(B)))
```

Comment: the `set()` around the tuple of the zip sadly doesnt achieve anything. because `((1,2),(1,3))` and `((1,3),(1,2))` are different values for the set.

And that is what i get with this result with `A = [1,1]` and `B = [2,3]`

Comment: i could probably sort the tuples and then apply a set like

`set((tuple(sorted(list(zip(perm, B)))) for perm in set(permutations(A, len(B)))))`

this gives the desired result. i just doubt that it is faster than keeping and processing the duplicate assignments

Comment: `list(set(tuple(sorted(zip(A, p))) for p in it.permutations(B)))` would order the pairs with the tuple

Comment: that gives me exactly the result i need. the question now is what is fastest. because the duplicate entries in that list dont make my result wrong but just slow it down. but so does having to sort and transform the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

To account for both lists having duplicates, it is indeed easiest to filter duplicates of the outcome from mapping the permutations of a list to another list.

To de-duplicate tuples while maintaining their order and counts, you can convert the permutations of tuples to a set of frozensets of `collection.Counter` items, and then use the `Counter.elements` to convert the tuple counts back to tuples.

Below is an example where there are duplicates in both input lists:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import Counter

A = [0,0,1,1]
B = [2,3,3,3]

[
    tuple(Counter(dict(s)).elements())
    for s in {
        frozenset(Counter(zip(A, p)).items())
        for p in permutations(B)
    }
]
```

This returns:

```
[((0, 3), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 3)), ((1, 2), (0, 3), (0, 3), (1, 3))]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/LongtermNaturalFiletype

Answer (score 1):

You can take sets of A and B, then take the product from itertools

```
from itertools import product
A = [1,1]
B = [2,3]
result = list(product(set(A), set(B)))
print(result) # prints [(1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: for `A = [1,1,5]` `B = [2,3,6]` this gives me `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 6), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 6)]`

but i want `[[(5, 2), (1, 3), (1, 6)], [(1, 2), (5, 3), (1, 6)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 6)]]`